# CircleCI is timing out, and it's related to node and eslint

Tags: node.js, eslint, circleci

CircleCI is timing out while running eslint using node.

I get the following error message:

```
command ... took more than 10 minutes since last output
```

On my local machine, it only takes 17 seconds.

(Answer below...)

Answer (score 1):

I logged into CircleCI using "Debug via SSH". I confirmed that eslint was hanging. Then, I figured out how to get more debugging information:

```
DEBUG=eslint:cli-engine eslint .
```

After a long time, Node actually crashed:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

  345472 ms: Scavenge 1399.8 (1457.3) -> 1399.8 (1457.3) MB, 38.0 / 0 ms (+ 6.8 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
  348177 ms: Mark-sweep 1399.8 (1457.3) -> 1399.8 (1457.3) MB, 2705.8 / 0 ms (+ 8.7 ms in 2 steps since start of marking, biggest step 6.8 ms) [last resort gc].
  350927 ms: Mark-sweep 1399.8 (1457.3) -> 1399.5 (1457.3) MB, 2749.7 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0xd2a8c0b4629 <JS Object>
    1: /* anonymous */ [/home/ubuntu/website-django/static/node_modules/babel-eslint/babylon-to-espree/toToken.js:~1] [pc=0x33a525e2adb9] (this=0x1e91da709851 <JS Global Object>,token=0x349f83a2fc01 <a Token with map 0x3b6a9d8c2e31>,tt=0x2c0cfbd85ee1 <an Object with map 0x3b6a9d898959>,source=0x3314aa504101 <Very long string[1177579]>)
    2: toTokens [/home/ubuntu/website-django/static/node_mod...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Finally, I realized that it was trying to lint my build directory which contained a bunch of third-party libraries, including Highchart, which are known to cause eslint problems because they're so big.

I added this to my .eslintignore:

```
build/**
```

Then, the problem went away.

The take home message is: make sure you're only linting the things you need to lint.